# UTC in seconds to local time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

As I've never dealt with dates before in any context, I'm a little lost.

I receive an NSNumber as a UTC time (e.g. 1392061005) and I want to convert it into the local time.  I'm hoping to get the:

- NSString of the month
- NSString of the day (e.g. 5, 30)
- NSString of the time (e.g. 7:30 am)

There are a few questions related but all of the ones that I could find were first given a string such as June 1 14:23:12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[Your_UTC_Number integerValue]];
    NSLog(@"date:%@ ", date);
```

Comment: sometimes it's just that simple.  Having never dealt with times before I'm starting to appreciate their complexity.  Thanks a ton; will mark as correct when timelimit is up

Answer (score 2):

Use NSDate:

```
- (instancetype)initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
```

Just make sure if your input number is in seconds or millis.